# creating a file from input stream

Tags: c#, filestream

My component will receive a pdf file as a filestream from which I will need to create a file.

For testing purposes I am trying to read a file using the filestream object and recreate it at a different location. But the recreated file is created blank. the recreated file has the same number of pages though...

This is the code

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(_filePath);
str = sr.ReadToEnd();
File.WriteAllText(@"C:\recreated.pdf", str);
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I save a stream to a file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/411592/how-do-i-save-a-stream-to-a-file)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a start, you're using a `StreamReader` even though PDFs are binary data. You don't want to write text - you want to read and write *binary* data.

See [my answer to a similar question yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934295/2934308#2934308) (not exact duplicate, but similar) for more details and code.