# How do I deserialize a file into a .net web request object?

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, webrequest

I'd like to be able to deserialize a file containing a web request into some .NET structure that I could then use to make the request. The following is an example of the file;

```
POST http://127.0.0.1/Foo HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
User-Agent: MyAgent/1.0
Content-Type: text/xml
Host: 127.0.0.1
Content-Length: 14
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate

This is payload
```

Ideally, I'd like to be able to construct something like a `WebRequest` class which would give me access to headers, verbs etc. I could probably write something but I'd rather not have to deal with lots of edge cases.

I'd like to use it to drive some testing ...Are there any BCL types/methods that allow this?

Comment: You haven't asked a question

Comment: Your question doesn't really make sense. Deserialize a file containing a web request ?? What does that mean?

Comment: Really? Let me try again - If I post to a web page, it sends over the wire the text above. I capture that text in, say, fiddler, and save it to a text file. What I'd now like to do is use that file to reconstruct a web request object that I could use to replay the post to the web page.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand correctly, but you can use JSON.NET to serialize a .NET Class with all the necessary attributes for replaying the request into a JSON string structure which can then be deserialized later.

Comment: Why manually copy-pasting? If you are doing all that in your code, you can try what is mentioned here http://stackoverflow.com/a/2934308/125740

Comment: @Yahya That's not really relevant or helpful - I don't have a problem copying the request as it's caught in fiddler. *I need to get that request into something like a HttpWebRequest object*

Comment: @JasonHyland how are those requests generated? From code or you are intercepting?

Comment: @Yahya Caught from fiddler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing a simple parser for this.