# Uploading Files using InputStream in Generic Handler failes to save Headers or it fails to keep its actual content type

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, fine-uploader, generic-handler

Im using a JQUERY based file uploader and obviously as other file uploaders it posts the data to server. Am using Generic handler to handle the data.

When I use

```
Context.request.files(0).saveAs(mpath)
```

It works fine. If its image, it keeps as image in the server keeping all its exif, meta data and everything. Same as if it is any other types, the file doest not loses its basic instinct or content type.

But due to some situational factors Im using Inputstream

So my code is

```
    Dim inputStream As System.IO.Stream = context.Request.InputStream

    Using fileStream As System.IO.FileStream = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(tempFile)
        inputStream.CopyTo(fileStream)

    End Using
```

But in this case the files behaves as an unknown file. Loses all its features or content type.

So what I guess is when using **inputstream** way, it losing its header.. (Not sure thats the reason)

So how can we avoid this and the file to keep all its extra info and type when using **Stream**

Comment: it's not vb.net but I think this could help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934295/c-sharp-save-a-file-from-a-http-request#2934308

Comment: @ElmerDantas Sorry the way in that answer is same as mine expect its for downloading. But it is also using stream.copyto function which results the same

Answer (score 0):

Sorry..... I found the issue. That was because I was using request.inputstream.

It should be request.file(0).inputstream