# PDF upload encoding issue

Tags: c#, http, pdf, encoding, multipartform-data

I'll get straight to the point: how to upload PDF files from a C# backend into a HTTP web service inside a `multipart/form-data` request without the contents being mangled to the point of the file becoming unreadable? The web service documentation only states that text files should be `text/plain` and image files should be binary; PDF files are only mentioned as "also supported", with no mention of what format or encoding they should be in.

The code I'm using to create the request:

```
HttpWebRequest request;
string boundary = "---------------------------" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x");
request.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary;

using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream())) {
    sw.WriteLine("--" + boundary);

    sw.WriteLine("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"files\"; filename=\"" + Path.GetFileName(filePath) + "\"");

    sw.WriteLine(filePath.EndsWith(".pdf") ? "Content-Type: application/pdf" : "Content-Type: text/plain");

    sw.WriteLine();
    if (filePath.EndsWith(".pdf")) {

        // write PDF content into the request stream
    }
    else sw.WriteLine(File.ReadAllText(filePath));
    sw.Write("--" + boundary);
    sw.Write("--");
    sw.Flush();
}
```

For simple text files, this code works just fine. However, I have trouble uploading a PDF file.

- Writing the file into the request body using `StreamWriter.WriteLine` with either `File.ReadAllText` or `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(File.ReadAllBytes)` results in the uploaded file being unreadable due to .NET having replaced all the non-UTF-8 bytes with squares (which somehow also increased file size by over 100 kB). Same result with UTF-7 and ANSI, but UTF-8 results in the closest match to the original file's contents.
- Writing the file into the request body as binary data using either `BinaryWriter` or `Stream.Write` results in the web service rejecting it outright as invalid POST data. `Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary` (indicated by the documentation as necessary for `application/http`, hence why I tried) also causes rejection.

What alternative options are available? How can I encode PDF without .NET silently replacing the invalid bytes with placeholder characters? Note that I have no control over what kind of content the web service accepts; if I did, I'd already have moved on to base64.

Comment: had you tried use `HttpClient`  with `MultipartFormDataContent`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934295/c-sharp-save-a-file-from-a-http-request

Comment: @DavidTansey Stream.CopyTo() does not work either, web service rejects it as invalid POST data.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, my bad. The multipart form header and the binary data were both correct but were in the wrong order because I didn't `Flush()` the `StreamWriter` before writing the binary data into the request stream with `Stream.CopyTo()`.

Moral of the story: if you're writing into the same `Stream` with more than one Writer at the same time, *always `Flush()` before doing anything with the next Writer*.